# React Help Needed - Components not updating when index increases

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I cannot get the component displayed to update when the index increases. I am able to console the proper component now but because the onClick is below the component that needs to update, it isn't changing. Can someone help me fix my code? i think I am close but cannot figure it out for the life of me.

This sign up page is where I would like to update the component. Essentially I want to display each component in the array once the next button is clicked. Currently the function console logs everything as I want it to, it's just a matter of getting it to appear in the

it is returning an error "cannot read property 'count' of null":

```
import React from 'react';
import Q1Name from './questions/Q1Name';
import Q2Birthday from './questions/Q2Birthday';
import Q3City from './questions/Q3City';
import Q4YouReady from './questions/Q4YouReady';
import Q5Setting from './questions/Q5Setting';
import Q6Length from './questions/Q6Length';
import Q7Email from './questions/Q7Email';

        class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            i: 0
        }
    }

    _handleClick() {
        const components = [Q1Name, Q2Birthday, Q3City, Q4YouReady, Q5Setting, Q6Length, Q7Email];

        if(this.state.i < components.length) this.setState({ i : this.state.i + 1});
    }

    //  handleIncrement() {
    //         this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    //     }}

    render() {
        const components = [Q1Name, Q2Birthday, Q3City, Q4YouReady, Q5Setting, Q6Length, Q7Email];
        const componentsToRender = components.map((Component, i) => (
            <Component key={i} />
        ));


        return (
            <div className = "container-fluid signup-page">
                <div className = "question-box">
                    {componentsToRender[this.state.i]}
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom btn-lg" onClick={() => this._handleClick}>Next Question!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignUpPage;
```

There are a few component types I am bringing in, age, birthday, email, and a few button clicks, etc.

```
import React from 'react';

class Q1Name extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onNext();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="questions q1" style={this.props.style}>
                <h1 id="question-h1">What is your name?</h1>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="name" className="form-control text-form custom-form" id="nameInput" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                    {/* <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom btn-lg" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Next Question!</button> */}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Q1Name;
```

Here is an example of the button option component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Q5Setting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="questions">
                <h1 id="question-h1">What is your ideal setting?</h1>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-custom-select btn-lg">Take me to the beach!</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-custom-select btn-lg">Anywhere outdoors!</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-custom-select btn-lg">All about the city!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Q5Setting;
```

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which line of your code do you think will change or update anything?

Comment: right now, the onClick function is updating the index and console logging the next component properly but I am not sure what I need to do to actually update the component that gets displayed.

Comment: oh you think changing `i` is going to update your view? have you read about `state` in react? that's what you're looking for. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I updated to add state but I don't think I am doing it correctly. it cannot read property count of null.. I am very new to react so just trying to learn and understand. I updated the code in my initial post to reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor initialise `state`

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props)
       this.state = { i: 0 }
}
```

Write helper method `handleClick`

```
_handleClick() {
      if(this.state.i < components.length) this.setState({ i : this.state.i + 1});
 }
```

Now reference `componentsToRender` using `i` in state
`componentsToRender[this.state.i]

Don't forget to call your helper function on click.

`onClick = {() => this._handleClick()}`

The idea is your app will only re-render when your state object changes. Follow that rule for your components you wish to re-erender on the fry.

Comment: Should I move the components array? I am getting the below error when I reference that code: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at _handleClick (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:5053), <anonymous>:106:22)

Comment: Yay! The question is showing back up. It's not clicking to the next item in the array though. I will update my code above so you can see how I have it set up

Comment: Ok, the error of state not being null is probably because you `_handleClick` method is not bound to the context. Make sure you use a function callback like I did in the example or use `.bind(this)` when you call the method

Comment: It is showing up but still will not change the component class when the button is clicked.

Comment: Then you may to just route to those components, or another idea I can give you is to render all components and then use an if or switch clause to show the required component. Render all of them in the .map call back. Then you can use a switch statement, to render the component when the index for that component is in state, else you render null. Hope I am making sense here.

Comment: I thought about the routing method. Can you have multiple routers? I am using one for my navbar currently. I like the idea of the switch statement and rendering everything based on the index of the component in state. Thank you for your help!